# How to update values in ticker by ajax in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, news-ticker

Like in financial or stock related web sites, I have implemented ticker on a page, but in certain interval I need to update the respective values without blinking. 
I have integrated [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Highly-Customizable-jQuery-Text-Scrolling-Plugin-Web-Ticker/example/) ticker on my page, but I need to make AJAX calls.
I have tried the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval('UpdateWatch();', 10000);
        });

        function UpdateWatch() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/UpdateWatch',
                success: function (html) {  
                      $('#myWatchDiv').html(html);                
                    }
                });
            }    
    </script>
```

The UpdateWatch function is giving me the data, but on success I see a little blinking or flicking while updating. How can I avoid the flicking?

Comment: Can you share the ticker with some sample data. The link specified is not working for me.

Comment: pls show `console.dir(html)` in success handler